# Onsenuiのmodifierのプリセット以外の指定について

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

先ほどons-list-headerの仕様を見ていたら、modifierが設定できそうでしたが、プリセットがありません。この場合modifierはどこかで自作できたりするのでしょうか？

そう言う記述が見当たらなかったのでご相談しました。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ons-list-header>`にはデフォルトで`list__header`及び`ons-list-header-inner`という2つのクラスが付加されていますが、`modifier`属性を指定すると3つ目のクラスが付加されます（`modifier="hoge"`とした場合、`list__header--hoge`というクラスが付加されます）。

ご指摘の通りプリセットはありませんが、この`list__header--hoge`に対して自分でCSSを当てることでデザインを修正することができます。

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。だとすると、他のmodifierの拡張も同様にやればいいということですね。助かりました。